# How to invoke an addon in firefox using selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

can i invoke an addon from firefox/chrome using selenium.My requirement is, i have to click and open an addon from firefox and do some action.Say i have to invoke script cover addon in firefox

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following with Firefox:

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.addExtension(new File(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("path/to/.xpi").getFile()));
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

I'd be willing to bet that setting something up for Chrome would be quite similar.  Note the above is for Selenium 2.

Edit for RC instructions:

You'll need to run the server as such (after creating the profile in the profile manager):

```
java -jar selenium-server.jar -firefoxProfileTemplate “<Selenium Profile Directory>”
```

You can take a look at further instructions [here](http://girliemangalo.wordpress.com/2009/02/05/creating-firefox-profile-for-your-selenium-rc-tests/).

Comment: is it possible with selenium RC?